# Multiselect Dropdown is updating only first dropdown if there are multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, checkbox, drop-down-menu, tags, multi-select

Below is the HTML & JS for the multiselect dropdown field.
The problem is if I select the options from 2nd or any other dropdown, only first dropdown gets updated and others doesnt work.

If I select the Research Report option from second dropdown, then a tag should be created in the second dropdown like the first one.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let fieldContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".field");
  fieldContainers.forEach((fieldContainer, index) => {
    let checkbox = fieldContainer.querySelectorAll(`#divOptions input`);
    let inputCheckbox = fieldContainer.querySelector("#inputCheckbox");
    let unorderedList = document.createElement("ul");
    unorderedList.className = "filtertags";

    for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
      checkbox[i].addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        if (e.target.checked) {
          let liTag = `<li class="txt-16-500">${checkbox[i].value}<i class="remTag"><svg width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M10 1.00714L8.99286 0L5 3.99286L1.00714 0L0 1.00714L3.99286 5L0 8.99286L1.00714 10L5 6.00714L8.99286 10L10 8.99286L6.00714 5L10 1.00714Z" fill="#FEFEFE"/>
                        </svg></i>
                      </li>`;
          unorderedList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", liTag);
          let remIcon = unorderedList.lastElementChild.querySelector(".remTag");
          remIcon.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            remIcon.parentElement.remove();
            checkbox[i].checked = false;
            updateInputCheckboxDisplay();
          });
        } else {
          let allLi = unorderedList.querySelectorAll("li");
          allLi.forEach(function(li) {
            if (li.innerText === checkbox[i].value) {
              li.remove();
            }
          });
        }
        updateInputCheckboxDisplay();
      });
    }

    const updateInputCheckboxDisplay = function() {
      inputCheckbox.style.display = unorderedList.childNodes.length > 0 ? "none" : null;
    };

    inputCheckbox.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", unorderedList);
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="field">
      <p class="txt-14">Status</p>
      <div class="custom-combobox-container">
        <div class="custom-combobox" onclick="showOptions(this)">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Select Status" id="inputCheckbox" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="options-container" id="divOptions">
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="one">
            <input type="checkbox" id="one" value="All" /> All
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="two">
            <input type="checkbox" id="two" value="Drafts" />
            Drafts
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="three">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="three"
              value="Approved"
            />
            Approved
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="four">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="four"
              value="Published"
            />
            Published
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="five">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="five"
              value="Submitted"
            />
            Submitted
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="six">
            <input type="checkbox" id="six" value="Updated" />
            Updated
          </label>
          <label class="txt-reg-400" for="seven">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id="seven"
              value="Rejected"
            />
            Rejected
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: Image for Reference]

Comment: There's only one set of checkboxes in your snippet.

Comment: Even If I add 2 or 3 more fields, It updates only the first dropdown.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. I don't see any dropdowns in your code. Dropdown = `<select>`

Comment: If you're calling the group of checkboxes a dropdown, there's only one of that in your HTML.